# Disable the legend double click event

Tags: r, plotly, legend, r-plotly

How do I disable the "Double click on legend to isolate one trace" interaction in plotly for R? I want a double click to just have the effect of two clicks.

Here is an example on how to do this with Javascript:

```js
Plotly.newPlot('graph', [{
  y: [1, 2, 1]
}, {
  y: [3, 4, 2]
}])
.then(gd => {
  gd.on('plotly_legenddoubleclick', () => false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

It uses `gd.on('plotly_legenddoubleclick', () => false)`.
I do not know how to translate this to R.

Example in R:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(y = c(1,2,1), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph")    %>%
  add_trace(y = c(3,4,2), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think javascript is necessary for this anymore, if it was in 2018. You can achieve this outcome directly in R by setting the legend's [`itemdoubleclick`](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-legend-itemdoubleclick) attribute via `layout()`:

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(y = c(1,2,1), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph") %>%
  add_trace(y = c(3,4,2), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph") %>%
  layout(legend = list(itemdoubleclick = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks! Not using R these days, but if someone confirms, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @PascalIv I confirm that the proposed solution works indeed (R version 4.0.3, plotly version 4.9.3). All layout-related settings are listed here https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-legend.

Answer (score 4):

You could add similar JavaScript code to your R code by using `htmlwidgets`.

- Select your mai-n Plotly DOM object
- Overwrite the event listener
- Add it to your R Plotly object

Notes:

- Update Plotly to the latest developer version via `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`
- If it doesn't work in RStudio, you'll need to export the graph as HTML

  ```
  library(plotly)
  library(htmlwidgets)

  p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(y = c(1,2,1), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph", type='scatter')    %>%
    add_trace(y = c(3,4,2), x = c(1,2,3), mode= "graph", type='scatter')

  javascript <- "var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];
  myPlot.on('plotly_legenddoubleclick', function(d, i) {return false});"
  p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete(javascript), data=list(''))
  p
  ```